# Affect all elements that doesn't have an index of?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide all elements with class `.dropdown-menu` except the 2nd one:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').not().eq(1).hide();
```

But it's not working, How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu:not(:eq(1))').hide();
```

---

You were using [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) incorecctly, here is the solution using [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) (it accepts a selector!):

```
$('.dropdown-menu').not(':eq(1)').hide();
```